# How to calculate relative and absolute precision for an expression with specified type

Tags: c++

I want to compare relative and absolute precision for an expression (ie. (x+y)/k)
when using float vs doubles. How Can I do it?

What type meets the following requirements for this expression:

**relative tolerance:** 1e-05

**absolute tolerance:** 1e-08

Example function:

```
<type> calc(<type> x, <type> y, <type> k){
    return (x+y)/k;
}
```

Comment: it is not completely clear what you want to do or what your problem is. You could evaluate the expression for some input with known exact result and calculate absolute and relative errors

Comment: How Can I know the exact result?

Comment: eg result of `(1+1)/2` is `1`

Comment: This function will return 1 for floats and doubles.

Comment: it was an example (not a good one). I am just trying to find out what you want to do, because your question is unclear. For example the absolute error can be anything and depends on the values of `x`,`y` and `k`

Comment: It would be nice if be able to generate some results with the exact result, but I'm not able to do it. I'm looking for a method that allows me to generate the exact values so I will be able to calculate the precision.

Answer (score 1):

> What type meets the following requirements ...

None (at least not floating point type).

Your requirements are not specific enough and consequently cannot be satisfied for all possible input. Consider `x = 1e100`, `y = 1e20` and `k = 1`. As neither `float` nor `double` have 80 digits the result will be `1e100` and the absolute error is as big as `1e20`!

I suppose you misunderstood the actual requirements, because only an arbitrary precision type can ensure such requirements on absolute precision. Not `double` and not `float`.